# how do make flexbox responsive in mobile?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

How can I make this flexbox responsive for mobile? i.e all elements in a column direction after detecting the width of the screen.

Also, make the font size responsive as well?

This is my CSS:

```css
.do-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  //box-sizing: border-box;
}

.do-flex  > div {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  margin: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="do-flex">
  <div class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus iste, aut praesentium recusandae quisquam ut fugit minus distinctio beatae architecto?</div>
    <div class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus iste, aut praesentium recusandae quisquam ut fugit minus distinctio beatae architecto?</div>
      <div class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus iste, aut praesentium recusandae quisquam ut fugit minus distinctio beatae architecto?</div>  <div class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus iste, aut praesentium recusandae quisquam ut fugit minus distinctio beatae architecto?</div>
</div>
```

Should I use max-width for this?

[image: flexbox here]

Answer (score 0):

Use media-queries for responsive design:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: whatever font-size you want
}
```

And then adjust any values you want inside the media-query.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: :D, should we use order to make grid like the above pic ??

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: to make grid like above, what i mention on css above only grid for each items, not same like on above

Comment: Without the rest of your code I can't really make any more suggestions. Could you post a working example on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0):

**// HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-item" id="open" data-expanded=true>
            <div class = "column-header">Open</div>
            <div class = "card">
                <div class = "card-title">Aufgabe 1</div>
                <div class = "card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item" id="inProgress" data-expanded=true>
            <div class="column-header">In Progress</div>
            <div class = "card">
                <div class = "card-title">Aufgabe 2</div>
                <div class = "card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</div>
            </div>
            <div class = "card">
                <div class = "card-title">Aufgabe 4</div>
                <div class = "card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item" id="done" data-expanded=true>
            <div class="column-header">Done</div>
            <div class = "card">
                <div class = "card-title">Aufgabe 3</div>
                <div class = "card-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut 
                    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**// CSS Code**

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: khaki;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: lightgray;
  margin: 3px;
  max-width: 20rem;
}

.flex-item[data-expanded="false"] {
  flex: 0 auto;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  min-width: 0px;
}

.column-header {
  border-bottom: medium mediumblue solid;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.column-header:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-expanded="false"] > .card .card-content,
[data-expanded="false"] > .card .card-title {
  display: none;
}

[data-expanded="false"] > .column-header {
  border: none;
  border-right: medium mediumblue solid;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.card {
  border: thin black solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

[data-expanded="false"] > .card {
  border: none;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-item[data-expanded="false"] {
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    flex: 0 auto;
  }
  [data-expanded="false"] > .column-header {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: medium mediumblue solid;
  }
}
```

**//JS Code**

```
window.onload = function() {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".flex-item");
  console.log(nodes);
  for (const node of nodes) {
    node.addEventListener("click", function(elem) {
      switchExpand(elem);
    });
  }
};

function switchExpand(elem) {
  const isExpanded = JSON.parse(
    elem.target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-expanded")
  );
  console.log(elem);
  elem.target.parentNode.setAttribute("data-expanded", !isExpanded);
}
```